# web2py components

Tags: web2py, web2py-modules

I would like to load different web2py components in the same view, but not  at the same time. I have 5 .load files which have form fields for a different scenario, these are called dynamically by an onchange select script. Is it possible with web2py to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but in that case, don't use the `LOAD()` helper in the web2py view, as that will generate Javascript that loads the component immediately upon page load. Instead, create a div with an id to hold the component, and have your `onchange` event handler call the `web2py_component()` function with the id of the div as the target:

```
<div id='mycomponent'></div>

<script>
$(function() {
  $('some_selector').change(function() {
    web2py_component('{{=URL('default', 'mycomponent')}}', target='mycomponent');
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, I figured it out. It's working now. 1 one more question does each .load file have to have a function named after it in the controller, cause mine does not work when i remove those functions.

Comment: The .load files are just views -- they do nothing on their own. Like any action, components require a controller function. When the function returns, its associated view (i.e., the .load file) is executed. Note, component view files need not have a .load extension. That is just a convention. It can be useful when a component redirects, as the .load extension will be passed on in the redirect.